# Write a GDX in python using lists

Tags: python, gdx-ai

I've tried this but error message

```
import gdx2py as gdx2py
from gdx2py import GdxFile, GAMSSet, GAMSScalar, GAMSParameter
import pandas as pd
with GdxFile('/path/to/gdx/file.gdx', mode='w') as gdx:
    gdx['set1'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # Write a simple set
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import gdx2py

with gdx2py.GdxFile('/path/to/gdx/file.gdx', mode='w') as gdx:

    set1 = gdx2py.GAMSSet("set1", domain="a b c")
    gdx.append(set1)

    param_data = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}
    param1 = gdx2py.GAMSParameter("param1", domain=set1, data=param_data)
    gdx.append(param1)

    scalar1 = gdx2py.GAMSScalar("scalar1", value=42.0)
    gdx.append(scalar1)
```